# Corrections in Left Outer Join Query to work with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want results from three tables where the results from the first table are must. For this I used Left Outer Join to link tables on the basis of **sno** (Primary Key). The query runs fine but I have an added complexity when I want to pick results from the third table on different criteria.

The question will clear when seeing how I am trying to retrieve results:

```
SELECT * FROM tw_main MainTable 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_details TW
        ON TW.sno = MainTable.sno
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails CWR
        ON CWR.sno = MainTable.sno WHERE CWR.twcatname = 'CWR'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails OHT
        ON OHT.sno = MainTable.sno WHERE OHT.twcatname = 'OHT'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails DS
        ON DS.sno = MainTable.sno WHERE DS.twcatname = 'DS'             
    WHERE
        MainTable.sno = 420;
```

This query works fine if I use the third table (tw_typedetails) only once, but I want separate resultset from the same table but with different WHERE clause.

What corrections are needed? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. This query is supposed to run from Crystal Reports command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of `where` clauses too many.

Try using `and` instead.

```
SELECT * FROM tw_main MainTable 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_details TW
        ON TW.sno = MainTable.sno
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails CWR
        ON CWR.sno = MainTable.sno AND CWR.twcatname = 'CWR'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails OHT
        ON OHT.sno = MainTable.sno AND OHT.twcatname = 'OHT'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_typedetails DS
        ON DS.sno = MainTable.sno AND DS.twcatname = 'DS'             
    WHERE
        MainTable.sno = 420;
```

Comment: The query runs fine when run independently from within SQL Server, but when run from within Crystal Reports the CWR result is overlapped with the DS result. The OHT results are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tw_details TW
        ON TW.sno = MainTable.sno
           AND MainTable.sno = 420
```

Or allow `null` values in the `where` clause:

```
WHERE MainTable.sno is null or MainTable.sno = 420;
```

Comment: Is the WHERE clause not accurate when used in the end?